# Dealing With Multiple Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and currently trying to add a patient to an existing dentist appointment.  I am having difficulty setting up my views and controllers properly.  How can I properly accomplish this?

Note: With the way I have set things up, I can create an appointment and tie it to a dentist.  Of course, the patient_id is missing.

Models:

```
class Dentist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dentists
  belongs_to :patients
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :dentists, :through => :appointments
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151107052115) do
  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "dentist_id"
    t.integer  "patient_id"
    t.datetime "appt_date"
  end

  create_table "dentists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :commentable do
    resources :appointments
  end

  resources :dentists, concerns: :commentable
  resources :patients, concerns: :commentable
end
```

Dentists Controller:

```
class DentistsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dentist = Dentist.new
  end

  def create
    @dentist = Dentist.new(dentist_params)
    if @dentist.save
      redirect_to dentists_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
...
end
```

Appointments Controller:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dentist = Dentist.find(params[:dentist_id])
    @appointment = @dentist.appointments.new
  end

  def create
    @dentist = Dentist.find(params[:dentist_id])
    @appointment = @dentist.appointments.new(appt_params)
    if Appointment.exists?(:appt_date => @appointment.appt_date)
      render :new
    else
      @appointment.save
      redirect_to dentist_path(@dentist)
    end
  end
...
end
```

Patients Controller:

```
TBD
```

Dentists View (Show):

```
<p><%= @dentist.name %> DDS</p>

<% if @dentist.appointments.any? %>
  <% @dentist.appointments.each do |appt| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= appt.appt_date %></li>
      <p><%= link_to "Edit", edit_dentist_appointment_path(@dentist, appt) %> |
         <%= link_to 'Delete', dentist_appointment_path(@dentist, appt), :method => :delete,
             data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?'} %> |
         <%= link_to 'Add Patient', new_patient_path %></p>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are currently no appointments scheduled</p>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to 'Delete Dentist', dentist_path(@dentist), :method => :delete,
       data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?'} %></p>


<p><%= link_to 'Create an appointment', new_dentist_appointment_path(@dentist) %></p>

<p><%= link_to 'Return to list', root_path %></p>
```

Comment: You haven't specified what exactly is your problem.  Are you getting an error? If so you should post it here.

Comment: I just don't know how to add a patient to an existing dentist appointment.  I'm drawing a blank with regards to what I should be doing with my views and controllers.  Essentially, if I've created an appointment for a dentist, how then do I create a patient and, at the same time, update my appointments table with the patient_id?  Is there a way to accomplish this with a single form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to Rails

Welcome!

---

You need to change your `belongs_to` references to be *singular*:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dentist
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

--

Because I can't see where you're trying to achieve this functionality, I'll show you what I'd do (using the `appointment#edit` action):

```
#app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @appointment = Appointment.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @appointment = Appointment.find params[:id]
      @appointment.save appointment_params
   end

   private

   def appointment_params
      params.require(:appointment).permit(:dentist_id, :patient_id, :appt_date)
   end
end 

#app/views/appointments/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :patient_id, Patient.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

If you're trying to set the `patient` from your `appointments#create` method, you'll be best doing this:

```
#app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @dentist = Dentist.find params[:id]
      @appointment = @dentist.appointments.new
   end

   def create
      @dentist = Dentist.find params[:id]
      @appointment = @dentist.appointments.new appointment_params
   end

   private 

   def appointment_params
     params.require(:appointment).permit(:dentist_id, :patient_id, :appt_date)
   end
end

#app/views/appointments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :patient_id, Patient.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  Fantastic solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking, is can you create an appointment through both the Dentist model and the Patient model at the same time `eg. @dentist.@patient.apointment.new`
you cannot do that. Based on the relationships you have set up, you will either want to create the appt from the Dentist, like you have now, and pass in the patient ID as an attribute, or vice-versa. OR, create through your Appointment model `eg. Appointment.new(dentist: @dentist, patient: @patient, ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  If I were to follow either of your solutions, what would my views and controllers end up looking like?